# Need to ID a chart software

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics

Hello im looking for a nice chart software and I remembered one that i really liked the look of.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/geatS.jpg
You can see it in that picture but I've searched and I cannot find anything like it. I'm guessing that it at least is in Javascript since it's displayed dynamically Anyone know what it is? Also if you know what software did the bars to come with it.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same but [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/%20FusionCharts) can do similar..